# What's going to happen to old links once we get a domain?

Tags: support, public-beta, domain-name

I'm currently using links to the `webapps.stackexchange.com` and `meta.webapps.stackexchange.com` domains. Additionally, now that the site is in public beta, search engines are indexing pages at these domains too.

What happens when we get our own domain? Will there be a 301 (permanent) redirect set up?

Comment: It also applies to links within the site - duplicate questions etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there will be a 301 (permanent) redirect.